# Taking the Inner Product of Tensors in Maple

Tags: inner-products, tensors, maple

I'm fairly new to using Maple and am having a bit of a hard time calculating the following inner product. Firstly, I define the tensors (which to this end I'm not certain they are correctly defined),

$with(Physics):$

$Setup(mathematicalnotation=true)$

$Setup(coordinatesystems=spherical):$
\begin{equation}
ds2 := - dt^2 + a(t)^2 /( 1-k*r^2)dr^2 + a(t)^2*r^2dtheta^2 + a(t)^2*r^2*sin(theta)^2dphi^2;
\end{equation}
$Setup(coordinates = spherical, metric = ds2);$
\begin{equation}
e_{\mu}^{\nu} = \text{Matrix}(4, {(1,1)= \frac{a(t)}{\sqrt{(1-kr^2)}}, (2,2)=a(t)r, (3,3)=a(t)r\sin(\theta), (4,4)=1}, fill=0); (15) 
\end{equation}

Define ($\textbf{15}$)
\begin{equation}
f^{\mu}_{\nu} = \text{Matrix}(4, {(1,1)= \frac{\sqrt{(1-kr^2)}}{a(t)}, (2,2)= \frac{1}{(a(t)r)}, (3,3)=\frac{1}{(a(t)r\sin(\theta))}, (4,4)=1}, fill=0); (28)
\end{equation}

Define(($\textbf{28}))$

Thus, I defined two mixed tensors $e_{\mu}^{\nu}$ (one covariant and one contravariant index ) and $f^{\mu}_{\nu}$  (one contravariant and one covariant index).

Then, I try to take the following inner product between the two mixed tensors and the Christoffel symbols of the second kind, namely,

$e_{\nu}^{\alpha}f^{\sigma}_{\beta}\Gamma^{\nu}_{\sigma \mu}$,

(Maple code: e[nu, `~alpha`].f[`~sigma`, beta].Christoffel [`~nu`, sigma, mu])
where I used the Physics['.'] command . However, when I try taking this inner product, it returns unevaluated.

Did I define the mixed tensors incorrectly? Does it matter how you define the indices when you're gonna take the inner product? Because taking the inner product of simply e[mu, `~nu`].f[`~mu`, nu] also returns unevaluated. Also, I should mention that  e[mu, `~nu`] and f[`~mu`, nu] are inverses of each other, is there any way to define one and get the other, since, simply changing the way in which the indices are raised and lowered doesn't take the reciprocal of the components. This is in Maple 2019, anyhelp would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The author of Maple's `physics` package has answered here: https://www.mapleprimes.com/questions/228667-Maple-Inner-Product-For-Tensors-